# Why is this code not returning any values?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL and I'm trying to return values of CustomerLastName that starts with M, and I know there are some in the database, but they are not being returned. I see CustomerLastName and CustomerFirstName but no names.

```
SELECT 'CustomerFirstName', 'CustomerLastName'

FROM customer

WHERE LEFT(CustomerLastName, 1 = 'M ');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the *Single Quotes* from select statement

```
SELECT CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName

FROM customer

WHERE LEFT(CustomerLastName, 1 = 'M ');
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as the incorrect quotes in the select WHERE LEFT(CustomerLastName, 1 = 'M '); is not syntactically correct - and you should be seeing a raft of warnings.

Change to

```
WHERE LEFT(CustomerLastName, 1) = 'M';
```

And review [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)